# How to send HTTP request with trailers?

Tags: python, go, http, curl

MDN Web Docs stated that the trailer could be included in the request phase: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Trailer

I saw some trailers in the response examples. How could I send an HTTP request with trailers with Curl or Go/Python HTTP Client trailers rather than sending raw bytes to a socket to mock that behavior?

Comment: @deceze I thought the trailer was a response header before, but Envoy / Proxy WASM has a `Request Trailer` phase: https://github.com/proxy-wasm/proxy-wasm-cpp-sdk/blob/master/docs/wasm_filter.md#onrequesttrailers

Comment: I was thinking If my code has something to do with this phase, then I probably need to test with a real request.

Comment: In Go simply set the trailer values in [Request.Trailer](https://pkg.go.dev/net/http#Request.Trailer).